# Remove a sub-string from a string - C programming

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, substring, strip

I am trying to remove all `'\x00'` hexadecimal values in a particular string.

For example: if the string is `"Hello\x00World\x00\x00"`, I get `"Hello"` as output, but I need output as `"HelloWorld"`.

Can anyone help me in this?

```
char *strip(char *str, const char *sub) {
    size_t lenth = strlen(sub);
    if (lenth > 0) {
        char *p = str;
        while ((p = strstr(p, sub)) != NULL) {
            memmove(p, p + lenth, strlen(p + lenth) + 1); // returns a pointer to the destination
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `\x00` = synonymous with nullchar. Think about that in the context of how the functions you're calling actually work. Running your code in a *debugger* and examining the value of `lenth` after the first line of this function would show you immediately what the problem is.

Comment: Since strings in C are null terminated, any `\x00` character by definition marks the end of the string and there isn't anything else after it.  If you want to remove all zeros from an *array of bytes* (not a string), you'll need some other way to know where its end is.

Comment: Thanks for you reply :). Is there any way to remove hexadecimals from a string in C?

Comment: @NateEldredge His sequence of characters terminated by two consecutive zero characters.

Comment: I think you need to make up your mind if you need to remove "hexadecimals" - whatever that is supposed to mean, or if you wish to remove null terminators. Because the C pre-processor replaces hex escape sequences with their corresponding symbols, before your algorithm runs. That is: the C code won't be able to distinguish `"A"` from `"\x41"`.

Comment: @NiranjanMahesh do you confirm Vlad's assumption about your string being terminated by two consecutive `\0`s? Without this important info the question lacks clarity, imho.

Comment: I am not considering 2 consecutive \0's, I just want to remove **hexadecimal** values and null terminators in my string.

Comment: @NiranjanMahesh As I already explained to you some comments above, "remove hexadecimals" is a senseless requirement, because the "hexadecimals" in your code is a hexadecimal _escape sequence_ which does not even exist in run-time since they are replaced by the corresponding binary, just as letters in the source are. The only way to remove it would be through pre-processor tricks.

Comment: Voting to close this as unclear since nobody including the OP seems don't understand what the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward approach without using standard C string functions can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below provided that strings contain embedded terminating zero characters '\0' that shall be removed and two consecutive terminating zeroes mean the end of  string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * strip( char *s )
{
    char *p = s;
    const char *q = s;
    
    do
    {
        if ( !*q ) ++q;
        
        if ( p != q ) *p = *q;  

        ++p;
    } while ( *q++ );
    
    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = 
    { 
        'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\x00', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\x00', '\x00'
    };
    
    puts( strip( s ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
HelloWorld
```

An equivalent initialization of the character array can also look like

```
char s[] = "Hello\x00World\x00";
```

Or if to declare the source character array like

```
char s[] = 
{ 
    '0', '\x00', '1', '\x00', '2', '\x00', '3', '\x00', '4', '\x00', 
    '5', '\x00', '6', '\x00', '7', '\x00', '8', '\x00', '9', '\x00', '\x00'
};
```

then the program output will be

```
0123456789
```

Comment: Hey @vlad-from-moscow, It's really cool and it worked. What if there are 2 consecutive hexadecimals like "Hello\x00\x00World\x00" it is just considering the first set of characters before consecutive hexadecimals and the output will be "Hello".

Comment: @NiranjanMahesh There is needed some combination of zeroes to determine the end of the string. The function I provided based on that two consecutive zeroes mean the end of string. So For the string shown in your comment the function indeed will  output Hello.

Answer (score 0):

Please, convert all "\x00" to "\\x00". Both in the main string and the substring. The character '\' acts as an escape one. Therefore, if you want it to be taken as a character you have to add an extra one in front of it, in every use

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"


char *strip(char *str, const char *sub) {
    size_t lenth = strlen(sub);
    if (lenth > 0) {
        char *p = str;
        while ((p = strstr(p, sub)) != NULL) {
            memmove(p, p + lenth, strlen(p + lenth) + 1); // returns a pointer to the destination
        }
    }
    return str;
}



int main()
{       
        char str[] = "Hello\\x00World\\x00\\x00";
        char sub[] = "\\x00";
        printf("Start program\n str: %s\n sub: %s\n ", str, sub);
        printf("Result: %s\n", strip(str, sub));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you incorrectly specified the source string. It should contain hex character literals '\x00' instead of substrings like "\\x00".

Comment: The OP clearly wants to have null terminators. Please note that `\x00` is just another way to write the null terminator. It's a hex escape sequence, whereas `\0` is actually an octal escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A C string only has one null terminator, at the end. An algorithm working on a buffer containing multiple strings and any number of null terminators inside will need to know where the end is, because in that case it can no longer rely on a null terminator to mark the end. It's not clear if you meant to have 2 null terminators in a row to mark the end, or if you didn't even consider this problem.

The easiest way to fix it is to pass along a buffer size. Other alternatives would be to use some special symbol to mark the end. If so you could write the function like this:

```
char *strip(char *str, const char *sub, size_t size) 
{
  char* result = str;
  size_t length;

  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i+=length)
  {
    if(sub[i] == '\0')
    {
      length=1;
    }
    else
    {
      length = strlen(&sub[i]);
      memcpy(str, &sub[i], length);
      str += length;
    }
  }
  *str = '\0';
  return result;
}
```

The `if(sub[i] == '\0')` will also discard multiple null terminators in a row. Example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *strip(char *str, const char *sub, size_t size) 
{
  char* result = str;
  size_t length;
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i+=length)
  {
    if(sub[i] == '\0')
    {
      length=1;
    }
    else
    {
      length = strlen(&sub[i]);
      memcpy(str, &sub[i], length);
      str += length;
    }
  }
  *str = '\0';
  return result;
}

int main (void)
{ 
  char old_str[] = "Hello\0\0\0World\0How\0\0Are\0You?";
  char new_str[100];
 
  puts(strip(new_str, old_str, sizeof old_str));
}
```

Output: `HelloWorldHowAreYou?`

Comment: Thanks for your response :) . I am getting "Segmentation fault" for your first solution. I am not considering 2 consecutive \0's, I just want to remove **hexadecimal** values and null terminators in my string.

Comment: @NiranjanMahesh There's only 1 solution posted. You are probably calling it without passing on a sufficiently large destination buffer. This - like your original code - does not do in-place changes of the string.